# Trying to extract notification text to Activity (parse)

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm using [Parse](https://parse.com/) for push notifications in my app and I want to show the notification text in Activity when it is clicked. Here's how I'm trying to do it.

I created a new activity which is supposed to handle incoming notifications named PushNotification.class and I created this custom class inside it:

```
public class PushNotification extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG = "MyCustomReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
try {
      String action = intent.getAction();
      String channel = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Channel");
      JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));

      Log.d(TAG, "got action " + action + " on channel " + channel + " with:");
      Iterator itr = json.keys();
      while (itr.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String) itr.next();
        Log.d(TAG, "..." + key + " => " + json.getString(key));
      }
      String message = json.getString("alert");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    }
}
```

Now the main problem is that this line of code no longer works:

```
PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, PushNotification.class);
```

It underlines the "setDefaultPushCallback" part because appearantly it doesn't recognize PushNotification.class as Activity anymore.

I already tried asking this on parse.com but I didn't get much help there and I need to solve this as soon as possible.

Comment: Not sure about this.. replace the line with `PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(ACTIVITYNAME.this, PushNotification.class);` where `ACTIVITYNAME` is the Activity that you try to call the service from.

Comment: Doesn't work. The fact is that this code used to work until I replaced the main class of the PushNotification activity with the new custom class. It extends BroadcastReceiver instead of Activity, so it doesn't recognize it anymore.

Comment: I read a bit about parse, are you sure you calling the push call back currectly ? because i saw at parse.com that you should use `PushService.setDefaultCallback(CONTEXT,PushNotification.class);` note that there's no `Push`

Comment: Yes, I'm sure this is correct, it won't even give me an option to use it without "push". As I said, this worked fine before I started to edit PushNotification.class

Comment: Ok yeah i missed that... as i can see in this example they extented BroadcastReciver https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#receiving-responding/Android maybe you missed a step with the `manifest`

Comment: No, the manifest is fine. But as you can see in the manifest, it says "receiver" instead of "activity" while setDefaultPushCallback() requieres activity, not receiver. So there should probably be a different method to use when using custom receiver. But I looked everywhere and I can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Custom Push Notifications

Specify like this in ur Manifest.

```
 <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

    <receiver
        android:name="packagename.CustomParseBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="custom-action-name" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

---

In parse dashboard ,u can manually test push notifications  by setting text as message or Json format.

Actual JSON format is

{ "title": "Custom Push-Android", "objectId": "*****iuy", 
  "objectType": "type", "action": "custom-action-name" }

Copy this format and send a push manually ...

Then create ur broadcast class..

sample:

```
public class CustomParseBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 

{
  public static final String ACTION = "custom-action-name";


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    {
}

   ----
   ----  
}
```

I hope ,this helps...............

Comment: Thank you so much for your message , I found solution from : http://ahirazitai.blogspot.in/2013/05/push-notification.html , +1 for the kind message. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're switching from responding to the push with an activity, you have to specify the broadcast receiver in your manifest (see [Responding to an Intent](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#receiving-responding/Android)):

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.PushNotification">
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="com.example.UPDATE_STATUS" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This **replaces** the PushService.setDefaultCallback call.  For this to work, you also have to specify the action in your JSON payload as so:

```
{"action":"com.example.UPDATE_STATUS", "alert":"Your message here"}
```